# return to event handler in xaml from c#

Tags: c#, xaml

In VS, if I create a new event handler in XAML like ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick" , I can right click on this or hit f12 and it will take me to the c# behind.

Is there a way to get from the c# back to the XAML? Like can I right click or hotkey on "private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)" and return to the exact event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this by default in Visual Studio.

Add-ons such as Resharper or Telerik JustCode will add this, but otherwise you're best off just using good old CTRL-F to search your project

Comment: Ah ok. I see. Thank you.